# Given $x,y,z>0$: $\frac{2}{3x+2y+z+1}+\frac{2}{3x+2z+y+1}=(x+y)(x+z)$. Find Minimum Value Of: $P=\frac{2(x+3)^2+y^2+z^2-16}{2x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Given $x,y,z>0$: $\frac{2}{3x+2y+z+1}+\frac{2}{3x+2z+y+1}=(x+y)(x+z)$ $(1)$

Find Minimum Value Of:
$P=\frac{2(x+3)^2+y^2+z^2-16}{2x^2+y^2+z^2}$

I found $2x+y+z\geq 2$ from (1) but it not work :(

Could some one help me solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why I have this reslut:

since Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,we have
$$\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}\ge\dfrac{4}{x+y}$$
so 
$$\dfrac{2}{3x+2y+z+1}+\dfrac{2}{3x+2y+z+1}\ge \dfrac{8}{6x+3y+3z+2}\ge \dfrac{8}{6x+3\sqrt{2(y^2+z)}+2}$$
other hand
$$(x+y)(x+z)\le\dfrac{(2x+y+z)^2}{4}\le\dfrac{(2x+\sqrt{2(y^2+z^2)})^2}{4}$$
let
$$2x+\sqrt{2(y^2+z^2)}=u>0$$
use this condition we have
$$\dfrac{u^2}{4}\ge\dfrac{8}{3u+2}\Longrightarrow u^2(3u+2)\ge 32$$
so
$$\Longrightarrow 3u^3-6u^2+8(u+2)(u-2)\ge 0\Longrightarrow (u-2)(3u^2+8u-16)\ge 0$$
$$\Longrightarrow (u-2)(3u-4)(u+4)\ge 0$$
so
$$0<u\le\dfrac{4}{3},u>2$$
so when $0<u\le\dfrac{4}{3}$,then we have
$$\sqrt{2(y^2+z^2)}\le\dfrac{4}{3}-2x\Longrightarrow y^2+z^2\le 2(\dfrac{2}{3}-x)^2$$
so
$$\dfrac{2(x+3)^2+y^2+z^2-16}{2x^2+y^2+z^2}=1+\dfrac{12x+2}{2x^2+y^2+z^2}\ge 1+\dfrac{12x+2}{2x^2+2(\dfrac{2}{3}-x)^2}$$
then It is to find it

But for $u>2$, it is clear is $0$?

Comment: $(u-2)(3u-4)(u+4)\ge 0$
so
$0<u\le\dfrac{4}{3}$

Comment: Could you tell me why not $u\ge 2$ ?

Comment: Hello,So I fell this problem is strange

Comment: this is my homework :D, i think it will find the maximum value, but i'm not sure the minimum doesn't exist :(

Comment: if we find the maximum,then my solution can works

Comment: Anyway, thanks and +1 :D